# json key value pairs manipulation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object, key-value

I have an issue.
I am trying to pull data from a table to display edit and submit on my node app.
It's a MySQL database and I have no control over it or its design.
It only has 2 columns

`PropertyName | value`

Now when I use knexJS I get my json object

`[{“propertyName”:  “jobNumbers”, “value”: “20”},{`

and so on.
I am trying to sort it server side that it does

`[{“jobNumbers”: “20”},{`

As this will be simpler to display and manipulate should more rows be added or removed later on as I am currently displaying the data like so

`$scope.data = response.data;
 $scope.nJobNumbers = parseInt($scope.data[0].value)`

Which isn’t the best

And help would be great

Comment: what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Array#map()`

```js
const arr = [{"propertyName": "jobNumbers", "value": "20"}];

const finalArr = arr.map(a=>{
  let x = {};
  x[a.propertyName] = a.value;
  return x;
});

console.log(finalArr)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much, was on the right track before but I had it inncorectly ordered cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for.

This makes a new object out of all given key values pairs, where the propertyNames will be an item on the object with associated value.

```js
function dataParser($data) {
    var result = {};
    for(var c = 0; c < $data.length;c++) {
        var item = $data[c];
        result[item.propertyName] = item.value;
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(dataParser([
{"propertyName":  "jobNumbers", "value": "20"},
{"propertyName":  "jobTime", "value": "2000"},
{"propertyName":  "jobParticipants", "value": "3"},
]));
```